# How to add a roles to Meteor user accounts?

Tags: node.js, meteor, roles, meteor-accounts

Meteor has this amazing package call `meteor add accounts-password` but currently what I want to do is, to distinguish between user types:

> customer
>
> company

There are two groups of users right now. I don't want customer to be able to view routes meant for users in the company group.

I'm fairly new to Meteor.

In node.js/express I would simply add middleware to solve this problem.

How would I hack this in Meteor?

Answer (score 0):

just a comment, but I'm sure there is a package for that. I would check out atmospherejs.com, or https://github.com/alanning/meteor-roles.

Comment: will go ahead and check it out

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add roles to users you can do it with Robomongo. After you install it you can just add whatever role you want to a particular user. Find the user in your database go to edit and add roles[somerole]. I think that in the package documentation it is written how to do that. I usually do it in this way when I should add an admin role for example. But in your case, I think that you could write a statement which adds the particular role to each account.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Meteor is based on node, so you can do pretty much whatever you want using low-level interfaces, or use anything from the NPM ecosystem.

There are several fairly popular roles packages that are Meteor-specific:

[alanning:roles](https://atmospherejs.com/alanning/roles) is by far the most popular and may be sufficient for your purposes.

Among other features, it allows you to add users to roles, which are plain strings, and check whether a user has a certain role when you want to perform authorization.

The author suggests using what is often considered as "permissions" for "roles", but this is not mandatory and you can choose whatever suits you.

Some of the other packages are more flexible/powerful, so check them out, take a look at their source and customize as desired.

My personal preference is a different package, but I don't want to turn this thread into an opinionated one.

Comment: Thank you for replying, I did add the alanning:roles.

Comment: But now I have this weird error which I created another post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34750893/problems-with-signup-in-meteor

Comment: @airsoftFreak, if you solved the issue, please mark one of the answers as the solution so that the question would be considered resolved.