# Problems with signup in Meteor

Tags: meteor

I used normal codes, to signup with Meteor, especially on the client side.
Normal code that works, meaning that whenever user created it would redirect the user to a profile page together with a session

Code that works

```
Template.signup.events({
   'submit form': function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();

      var email = event.target.email.value;
      var username = event.target.username.value;
      var password = event.target.password.value;

      Accounts.createUser({
        email: email,
        username: username,
        password: username;
      });

      Router.go('/profile');
    }
});
```

The codes above work perfectly, it redirects and show the user's data, but I read discover meteor book, it says that its better to put the logic on the serverside, because Im planning to add roles https://github.com/alanning/meteor-roles

Here's the new code

client/signup.js

```
Template.signup.events({
    'submit form': function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();

      var signupData = {
        email: event.target.email.value,
        username: event.target.username.value,
        password: event.target.password.value,
        roles: ['customer']
      }

      Meteor.call('signup', signupData, function(error, result) {
        if (error) return alert(error.reason);
        // End
        if (result) {
          Router.go('/profile');
        }
      });
    }
  });
```

server/collections/user.js

```
Meteor.methods({
  signup: function(data) {

    id = Accounts.createUser({
      email: data.email,
      password: data.password,
      username: data.username,
    });

    if (data.roles.length > 0) {
      // Need _id of existing user record so this call must come
      // after `Accounts.createUser` or `Accounts.onCreate`
      Roles.addUsersToRoles(id, data.roles, 'default-group');
    }

    return data;
  }
});
```

The template below, is where Router.go will go to.

client/templates/accounts/profile.html

```
<template name="profile">
  {{#if currentUser}}

    <h3>Hello: {{ user.username }}</h3>
    <h4>Email: {{ user.email }}</h4>
  {{/if}}
</template>
```

client/templates/accounts/profile.js

```
Template.profile.helpers({
  user: function() {

    return {
      email: Meteor.user().emails[0].address,
      username: Meteor.user().username
    }
  }
});
```

For somehow the code above return no error, but the problem right now is that it doesn't show the user's object on profile html, but it did save the user's data to mongodb database?

So just want to clarify (My logic):

```
First I click signup -> will do Meteor.call -> then return, if there is no error --> Router.go
```

Comment: and the accounts is beign created?, since you are returnign the exact same data you are passing make the return to the Roles.addUsersToRoles and check what the result returns on the client

Comment: I check meteor mongo, the account is actually created, so I don't really know what is the actual problem right here.

Comment: what do you get with this?, the callback is good
`if (error){alert(error.reason) return;}
        // End
        if (result) {
         console.log(result)
          Router.go('/profile');
        }`

Comment: basically it returns the form data, that I have entered, let me share you the link of my meteor app.

Comment: http://moscovispeedy.meteor.com

Comment: @Ethaan any feedback? how do i debug this kind of application?

Comment: Have you looked at [Accounts.onCreateUser](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_oncreateuser)? You can add the group from there.

Comment: @MasterAM Haven't tried that yet. Whats the difference? From my understanding, Account.createUser is async? thats why it couldn't fetch the user's data object?

Comment: I edited the question, check it out.

Comment: do *not* accept groups from the client. And as far as I remember, you have the `_id` available in `onCreateUser`. As to the part where you don't necessarily have the `user` record available, the function call is independent from the data sync, so the user sync may not have been completed by the time the method callback runs. You should get it eventually, but not necessarily by the time you do the redirect.

Comment: IMO doing `router.go()` from the asynchronous callback isn't a good pattern. Furthermore you are bypassing the security aspects of the accounts package and transmitting the password directly to the server. `Accounts.onCreateUser` is a better approach like @MasterAM recommends.

Comment: @MasterAM can you show me code samples, so i can accept it.

Comment: @MichelFloyd can you me code samples, so i can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `Accounts.createUser(options)` from the *client* passing in your `data.roles` variable into the `options.profile` key.
2. On the *server*, use `Accounts.onCreateUser()`:

server:

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options,user){
  if ( options.profile.length > 0) {
    Roles.addUsersToRoles(user._id, options.profile, 'default-group');
  }
  return user;
});
```

[docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_createuser)